# 'git remote add' doesn't create repo

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I want to add remote repository from my shell but fail. I'm logged in and I'm in my local repository. So I enter this:

```
% git remote add origin https://github.com/<username>/example.git
% git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/<username>/example.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<username>/example.git (push)
```

So it seems that the repo has been created. But I see no new repo in my github account. And when I try to inspect the remote (or push anything there) it throws an error:

```
% git remote show origin
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/<username>/example.git/' not found
```

I tried googling similar questions but couldn't find the answer. Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Comment: If you're looking for ways to create a repo on GitHub other than using their GUI (like what I often prefer), check out the Hub CLI https://hub.github.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please have a look at [what you can do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @konekoya `hub` has been replaced with `gh` as the new official github cli. https://cli.github.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22git+remote+add%22+create

Answer (score 8):

`git remote add` does not "create the repo on github", it only links your local repo to an (existing) remote repo on github.

If `example.git` does not exist on github, you need to first create it (e.g : create an empty `example` repo through github's website).

After that, your regular git commands will work (`push`, `pull`, `remote show` ...).

Comment: Thanks, you're right!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a repo from the commandline, you can use the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/).

```
> gh repo create

Usage:  gh repo create [<name>] [flags]

Flags:
  -y, --confirm              Confirm the submission directly
  -d, --description string   Description of repository
      --enable-issues        Enable issues in the new repository (default true)
      --enable-wiki          Enable wiki in the new repository (default true)
  -h, --homepage string      Repository home page URL
      --internal             Make the new repository internal
      --private              Make the new repository private
      --public               Make the new repository public
  -t, --team string          The name of the organization team to be granted access
  -p, --template string      Make the new repository based on a template repository
```